# Cron status always remain "running" in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom module and added crontab file to run cron related task.

```
<group id="index">
    <job name="custom_orderprocess" instance="Test\Module\Cron\Check" method="execute">
        <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Although I can see the cron is scheduled but its status always remain "running" (never show success).
I have also for infinite loop (removing all code except return statement) but still no luck.

Can some one guide me

Comment: There is 2 second difference between created_at and scheduled_at in cron table but the important this is created_at is higher than scheduled_at.Does it cause issue ?

Comment: have you find issue?

Answer (score 0):

If cron is in running state then may be some error in your cron function.